# How to avoid compression when converting GeoTIFF to MBTiles?

Tags: gis, gdal, geotiff, mbtiles

I have been trying to convert a set of GeoTIFF files into MBTiles using gdal_translate (GDAL 3.0.4). My command looks as follows:

```
gdal_translate -of MBTiles -ot Byte -strict -scale 0 255 bogota.tif bogota.mbtiles
```

The GeoTIFF image is successfully converted to MBTiles, and I am able to render it using QGIS. However, it appears that the result is somewhat compressed, or that the new image has lost some resolution. I have been experimenting with the `-outsize` option and trying to force it to 100% of the original size of the image, but with no success.

**Is there a way to make sure that the result maintains the full resolution in the output?**

Here are some screenshots to compare the results:

## Before

[image]

## After

[image]

Note: GeoTIFF image is taken from the following link:
https://download.osgeo.org/geotiff/samples/made_up/bogota.tif

Comment: adding `-co "ZOOM_LEVEL_STRATEGY=UPPER"` helps a little

Comment: @YevKad It does! Thank you. However there is still a bit of blur in the output. But perhaps I should investigate zoom levels a bit further.

Comment: changing `-co "RESAMPLING=NEAREST"` removes the blur but still not the same as original

Comment: I found that a combination of the two works quite well. Still different from the original image, but this seems to give me the most accurate output so far.

Comment: You can also try -co "BLOCKSIZE=512" to create 512*512px tiles.